# How to create an ical export link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

In my javascript project, I got to the point that I created function that returns an icalendar and now I want to create an export link for it. Is there any package/tool that can help me do this or how can I do it ? I searched, but I coudn't find what I needed. Any suggestion would be very helpful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a simple route that returns .ics file.
You can either generate it on a fly during the request, or you can pre-generate it and store it somewhere and then just export.